# 'If' Condition Not Working As Expected In My C Code

Tags: c, visual-studio, gets

I am fully aware that this is due to some error overlooked by me while writing my text-based calculator project in C, but I have only started learning C less than a week ago, so please help me out!

Since the entire code is 119 lines, I'll just post the necessary snippet where the real issue lies: (There are no errors during compiling, so there is no error beyond these lines)

```
char choice[15];
    printf("Type 'CALCULATE' or 'FACTORISE' or 'AVERAGE' to choose function :\n");
    gets(choice);
    if (choice == "CALCULATE")
```

The bug is that even after perfectly entering CALCULATE or FACTORISE or AVERAGE, I still get the error message that I programmed in case of invalid input (i.e, if none of these 3 inputs are entered). It *SHOULD* be going on to ask me the first number I wish to operate on, as written for the CALCULATE input.

The code runs fine, no errors in VS 2013, and so I'm sure its not a syntax error but rather something stupid I've done in these few lines.

Comment: You don;t use `==` to compare string in C. You use `strcmp()`

Comment: Right, thanks, I'm coming from Python.... So what exactly should i do ?

Comment: also, never use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `==` you are comparing the addresses of 2 arrays, not the contents of the arrays.

Instead, you need to do:

```
if (strcmp(choice, "CALCULATE") == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that should fix it. I havent studied arrays yet, I was just going by what I had learnt from Python.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're question is, but that should be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to mention here:

1. **[Never use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917)** it has serious security issues and is removed from the latest standard. Use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.
2. To compare strings, you should use [`strcmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp), not `==`.

Comment: fgets() avoids buffer overflow, true, but increases unnecessary steps, and to be real, it is mostly only me who will use this project.

Comment: @AnAnt Whatever be the case, if you want to write correct and standard complaint code, you **cannot** use `gets()`.

Comment: I'm coding for myself, and i respect you standardised instincts, but for me and 4 of my friends it really wouldnt matter that much right ?

Comment: @AnAnt take your pick, but I'd suggest, if you're doing something, do it right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to compare a string literal with a char array. C isn't found those things being the same, since the '==' comparison operator is not implemented in that way.

You have two options for performing that comparison :

1) Use the strcmp() function, from *string.h* library

2) Manually comparing the chars in your array, and the string literal

Definitely, the first option is the easiest and cleanest one.

Comment: thanks, that I'll do this. I'm coming from Python, so I did it almost reflexively.